# Is there a cable-stop variant for the screw-in internal routing ports?

Tags: terminology, cable-routing

On my frame the internal routing "ports", the things that are screwed into the frame with a small hex-head screw, have ingress/egress holes large enough for cable housing to pass through it.  Is there a variant of these screw-ins that has a cable-stop, so bare cable could be used?  A bare cable would be easier to install and a handful of small cable donuts would keep things quiet. Do these things have a name?

Comment: Those ports are more or less unique to each manufacturer, so they would need to provide their own properly fitted adapter. I don't think you could find a one-size-fits-all adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't universal in any way. Depending on the bike/brand, there may be some out there that fit the same frame hole and do what you suggest in the case of a manufacturer trying to employ the tactic of re-using the same small parts, but that's not how it usually is.

Some frames are set up to allow a straight shot of cable like you suggest, but usually it would have that sort of housing stop if so. Running bare cables in a frame set up for continuous housing is generally not something that can work.